# Is stationary process necessarily ARMA?

Tags: time-series, arima, stationarity

Is a stationary process necessarily ARMA? Can anyone please explain why?

Answer (score 1):

No, not necessarily. ARMA processes have rational spectrum. You might have stationary processes with non-rational spectrum.

**EDIT:   Why ARMA's have rational spectrum?**

Consider an ARMA in the usual notation,
$$ \phi(B)y_t = \theta(B)\epsilon_t $$
where $B$ is the backshift operator and $\epsilon_t$ is white noise. Then (assuming $\phi(B)$ invertible),
$$y_t = \frac{\theta(B)}{\phi(B)}\epsilon_t$$
and the spectral density of $y_t$ is
$$f_y(\lambda) = \left|\frac{\theta(e^{-i\lambda})}{\phi(e^{-i\lambda})}\right|^2 \frac{\sigma_\epsilon^2}{2\pi}
$$
i.e. a constant (spectral density of the white noise) times a ratio of polynomials in $e^{-i\lambda}$.

See for more detail (with slightly different notation) 
[here](https://www.google.es/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwj63KDum_DUAhUFvRoKHeEFDRIQFggtMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.stat.berkeley.edu%2F~bartlett%2Fcourses%2F153-fall2010%2Flectures%2F17.pdf&usg=AFQjCNEe_5ngY3NFKoYKiCYZdBukm1mfJA).

Comment: Why do ARMA processes have rational spectrum? Is it a theorem?

Comment: Thanks for the edit. I couldnt quite understand the last step. Why is $f_y(\lambda)$ a rational spectrum?